# Passenger type mismatch in search request and response

Tags: sabre

I send 3 adults and 2 childs in search request(action: BargainFinderMax_RQ ) and in response(action: BargainFinderMax_RS) we receive 5 adults.

Sabre returns as info :

> CNN NOT APPLICABLE - ADT FARE USED - VERIFY RESTRICTIONS

I would like to ask if there is any parameter supplied that Sabre provides that will let me receive only given passenger type.

**Edit:** Here is the BargainFinderMaxRQ:

```
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ PrimaryLangID="En" Version="1.8.5" ResponseType="OTA" ResponseVersion="1.8.5" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
      <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="1">
        <DepartureDateTime>2016-08-26T12:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
        <DepartureWindow>00002359</DepartureWindow>
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="KRR" />
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="DLM" />
      </OriginDestinationInformation>
      <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="2">
        <DepartureDateTime>2016-09-02T12:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
        <DepartureWindow>00002359</DepartureWindow>
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="DLM" />
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="KRR" />
      </OriginDestinationInformation>
      <TravelPreferences>
        <TPA_Extensions>
          <DiversityParameters AdditionalNonStopsNumber="10" />
        </TPA_Extensions>
      </TravelPreferences>
      <TravelerInfoSummary>
        <SeatsRequested>5</SeatsRequested>
        <AirTravelerAvail>
          <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="3" />
          <PassengerTypeQuantity Age="8" Code="CNN" Quantity="2" />
        </AirTravelerAvail>
      </TravelerInfoSummary>
    </OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
  </s:Body>
```

Comment: Can you share your BFM request?

Comment: @fcarreno Thanks for comment, please see edit

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the error using the same request.
Getting a 'No availability' error back. It may be related to the country associated to my PCC, but anyway, it seems you're missing the POS element as the first one, after OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ.

You can include it this way:
<OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ.....>
 <POS>
            <Source PseudoCityCode="[YourPCCHere]">
               <RequestorID ID="1" Type="1">
                  <CompanyName Code="TN" />
               </RequestorID>
            </Source>
         </POS>
<OriginDestinationInformation.....>.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the XOFares element:

```
<!--"Value" (required) Indicator for whether to return only fares with a passenger type the same as the passenger type specified in the request.-->
<!--Value="true" Returns only fares with a passenger type the same as the passenger type specified in the request.-->
<!--Value="false" (default) Uses standard Bargain Finder Max logic.-->
<XOFares Value="true"/>
```