# SABRE BFM PassegerTypeQuantity response with a different type and number of passengers

Tags: sabre

This is my request to Sabre BFM:

```
{
  "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
    "Target": "Production",
    "OriginDestinationInformation": [
      {
        "DepartureDateTime": "2017-10-02T00:00:00",
        "DestinationLocation": {
          "LocationCode": "JFK"
        },
        "OriginLocation": {
          "LocationCode": "LAX"
        },
        "RPH": "1"
      },
      {
        "DepartureDateTime": "2017-10-27T00:00:00",
        "DestinationLocation": {
          "LocationCode": "LAX"
        },
        "OriginLocation": {
          "LocationCode": "JFK"
        },
        "RPH": "2"
      }
    ],
    "POS": {
      "Source": [
        {
          "PseudoCityCode": "4OMI",
          "RequestorID": {
            "CompanyName": {
              "Code": "TN"
            },
            "ID": "REQ.ID",
            "Type": "1"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "TPA_Extensions": {
      "IntelliSellTransaction": {
        "RequestType": {
          "Name": "50ITINS"
        }
      }
    },
    "TravelPreferences": {
      "ValidInterlineTicket": true,
      "CabinPref": [
        {
          "Cabin": "Y",
          "PreferLevel": "Only"
        }
      ],
      "TPA_Extensions": {
        "TripType": {
          "Value": "Return"
        }
      }
    },
    "TravelerInfoSummary": {
      "SpecificPTC_Indicator": false,
      "SeatsRequested": [
        4
      ],
      "AirTravelerAvail": [
        {
          "PassengerTypeQuantity": [
            {
              "Quantity": 2,
              "Code": "ADT",
              "Changeable": true
            },
            {
              "Quantity": 2,
              "Code": "CNN11",
              "Changeable": true
            },
            {
              "Quantity": 2,
              "Code": "INF",
              "Changeable": true
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is the response from Sabre BFM:

```
{
    "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRS": {
        "PricedItinCount": 0,
        "BrandedOneWayItinCount": 0,
        "SimpleOneWayItinCount": 0,
        "DepartedItinCount": 0,
        "SoldOutItinCount": 0,
        "AvailableItinCount": 0,
        "Version": null,
        "Success": null,
        "Warnings": null,
        "PricedItineraries": {
            "PricedItinerary": [{
                "AirItinerary": {
                    "OriginDestinationOptions": {
                        "OriginDestinationOption": [{
                                "FlightSegment": [{
                                        "DepartureDateTime": "2017-10-02T13:00:00",
                                        "ArrivalDateTime": "2017-10-02T18:33:00",
                                        "StopQuantity": 0,
                                        "FlightNumber": 424,
                                        "ResBookDesigCode": "Z",
                                        "ElapsedTime": 213,
                                        "DepartureAirport": {
                                            "LocationCode": "LAX"
                                        },
                                        "ArrivalAirport": {
                                            "LocationCode": "MSP"
                                        },
                                        "MarketingAirline": {
                                            "Code": "SY"
                                        },
                                        "ArrivalTimeZone": {
                                            "GMTOffset": -5.0
                                        },
                                        "TPA_Extensions": {
                                            "ValidatingCarrier": null,
                                            "eTicket": {
                                                "Ind": true
                                            },
                                            "Mileage": {
                                                "Amount": 1536
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "MarriageGrp": "O",
                                        "Equipment": [{
                                            "AirEquipType": "738",
                                            "content": ""
                                        }],
                                        "OnTimePerformance": null,
                                        "OperatingAirline": {
                                            "FlightNumber": 424,
                                            "Code": "SY",
                                            "content": ""
                                        },
                                        "DepartureTimeZone": {
                                            "GMTOffset": -7.0
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "DepartureDateTime": "2017-10-02T19:45:00",
                                        "ArrivalDateTime": "2017-10-02T23:35:00",
                                        "StopQuantity": 0,
                                        "FlightNumber": 249,
                                        "ResBookDesigCode": "Z",
                                        "ElapsedTime": 170,
                                        "DepartureAirport": {
                                            "LocationCode": "MSP"
                                        },
                                        "ArrivalAirport": {
                                            "LocationCode": "JFK"
                                        },
                                        "MarketingAirline": {
                                            "Code": "SY"
                                        },
                                        "ArrivalTimeZone": {
                                            "GMTOffset": -4.0
                                        },
                                        "TPA_Extensions": {
                                            "ValidatingCarrier": null,
                                            "eTicket": {
                                                "Ind": true
                                            },
                                            "Mileage": {
                                                "Amount": 1028
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "MarriageGrp": "I",
                                        "Equipment": [{
                                            "AirEquipType": "738",
                                            "content": ""
                                        }],
                                        "OnTimePerformance": null,
                                        "OperatingAirline": {
                                            "FlightNumber": 249,
                                            "Code": "SY",
                                            "content": ""
                                        },
                                        "DepartureTimeZone": {
                                            "GMTOffset": -5.0
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "ElapsedTime": 455
                            },
                            {
                                "FlightSegment": [{
                                        "DepartureDateTime": "2017-10-27T07:00:00",
                                        "ArrivalDateTime": "2017-10-27T09:05:00",
                                        "StopQuantity": 0,
                                        "FlightNumber": 240,
                                        "ResBookDesigCode": "Z",
                                        "ElapsedTime": 185,
                                        "DepartureAirport": {
                                            "LocationCode": "JFK"
                                        },
                                        "ArrivalAirport": {
                                            "LocationCode": "MSP"
                                        },
                                        "MarketingAirline": {
                                            "Code": "SY"
                                        },
                                        "ArrivalTimeZone": {
                                            "GMTOffset": -5.0
                                        },
                                        "TPA_Extensions": {
                                            "ValidatingCarrier": null,
                                            "eTicket": {
                                                "Ind": true
                                            },
                                            "Mileage": {
                                                "Amount": 1028
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "MarriageGrp": "O",
                                        "Equipment": [{
                                            "AirEquipType": "738",
                                            "content": ""
                                        }],
                                        "OnTimePerformance": null,
                                        "OperatingAirline": {
                                            "FlightNumber": 240,
                                            "Code": "SY",
                                            "content": ""
                                        },
                                        "DepartureTimeZone": {
                                            "GMTOffset": -4.0
                                        }
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "DepartureDateTime": "2017-10-27T10:05:00",
                                        "ArrivalDateTime": "2017-10-27T12:00:00",
                                        "StopQuantity": 0,
                                        "FlightNumber": 423,
                                        "ResBookDesigCode": "Z",
                                        "ElapsedTime": 235,
                                        "DepartureAirport": {
                                            "LocationCode": "MSP"
                                        },
                                        "ArrivalAirport": {
                                            "LocationCode": "LAX"
                                        },
                                        "MarketingAirline": {
                                            "Code": "SY"
                                        },
                                        "ArrivalTimeZone": {
                                            "GMTOffset": -7.0
                                        },
                                        "TPA_Extensions": {
                                            "ValidatingCarrier": null,
                                            "eTicket": {
                                                "Ind": true
                                            },
                                            "Mileage": {
                                                "Amount": 1536
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "MarriageGrp": "I",
                                        "Equipment": [{
                                            "AirEquipType": "73G",
                                            "content": ""
                                        }],
                                        "OnTimePerformance": null,
                                        "OperatingAirline": {
                                            "FlightNumber": 423,
                                            "Code": "SY",
                                            "content": ""
                                        },
                                        "DepartureTimeZone": {
                                            "GMTOffset": -5.0
                                        }
                                    }
                                ],
                                "ElapsedTime": 480
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "DirectionInd": "Return"
                },
                "AirItineraryPricingInfo": [{
                    "FareReturned": true,
                    "PricingSubSource": "MIP",
                    "PricingSource": "ADVJR1",
                    "LastTicketDate": "2017-09-29T00:00:00",
                    "PTC_FareBreakdowns": {
                        "PTC_FareBreakdown": [{
                                "FareBasisCodes": {
                                    "FareBasisCode": [{
                                            "BookingCode": "Z",
                                            "DepartureAirportCode": "LAX",
                                            "AvailabilityBreak": false,
                                            "ArrivalAirportCode": "MSP",
                                            "content": "ZT"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "BookingCode": "Z",
                                            "DepartureAirportCode": "MSP",
                                            "AvailabilityBreak": true,
                                            "ArrivalAirportCode": "JFK",
                                            "content": "ZT"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "BookingCode": "Z",
                                            "DepartureAirportCode": "JFK",
                                            "AvailabilityBreak": false,
                                            "ArrivalAirportCode": "MSP",
                                            "content": "ZT14"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "BookingCode": "Z",
                                            "DepartureAirportCode": "MSP",
                                            "AvailabilityBreak": true,
                                            "ArrivalAirportCode": "LAX",
                                            "content": "ZT14"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "PassengerTypeQuantity": {
                                    "Quantity": 2,
                                    "Code": "ADT",
                                    "Changeable": false
                                },
                                "PassengerFare": {
                                    "FareConstruction": {
                                        "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                                        "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                        "Amount": 229.77
                                    },
                                    "TotalFare": {
                                        "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                        "DecimalPlaces": 0,
                                        "Amount": 934.28
                                    },
                                    "Taxes": {
                                        "TotalFare": null,
                                        "Tax": [{
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "US1",
                                                "Amount": 55.02,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "ZP",
                                                "Amount": 13.09,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "ZP",
                                                "Amount": 13.09,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "ZP",
                                                "Amount": 13.09,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "ZP",
                                                "Amount": 13.09,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "AY",
                                                "Amount": 17.88,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "AY",
                                                "Amount": 17.88,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "XF",
                                                "Amount": 14.36,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "XF",
                                                "Amount": 14.36,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "XF",
                                                "Amount": 14.36,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "XF",
                                                "Amount": 14.36,
                                                "content": ""
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "BaseFare": {
                                        "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                                        "DecimalPlaces": 0,
                                        "Amount": 229.77
                                    },
                                    "EquivFare": {
                                        "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                        "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                        "Amount": 733.7
                                    }
                                },
                                "Endorsements": {
                                    "NonRefundableIndicator": true
                                },
                                "TPA_Extensions": {
                                    "FareCalcLine": {
                                        "Info": "LAX SY X/MSP SY NYC128.37SY X/MSP SY LAX101.40USD229.77END ZPLAXMSPJFKMSP XFLAX4.5MSP4.5JFK4.5MSP4.5"
                                    }
                                },
                                "FareInfos": {
                                    "FareInfo": [{
                                            "FareReference": "Z",
                                            "TPA_Extensions": {
                                                "SeatsRemaining": {
                                                    "Number": 9,
                                                    "BelowMin": false
                                                },
                                                "Cabin": {
                                                    "Cabin": "Y"
                                                },
                                                "Meal": {
                                                    "Code": "F"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "FareReference": "Z",
                                            "TPA_Extensions": {
                                                "SeatsRemaining": {
                                                    "Number": 9,
                                                    "BelowMin": false
                                                },
                                                "Cabin": {
                                                    "Cabin": "Y"
                                                },
                                                "Meal": {
                                                    "Code": "F"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "FareReference": "Z",
                                            "TPA_Extensions": {
                                                "SeatsRemaining": {
                                                    "Number": 9,
                                                    "BelowMin": false
                                                },
                                                "Cabin": {
                                                    "Cabin": "Y"
                                                },
                                                "Meal": {
                                                    "Code": "F"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "FareReference": "Z",
                                            "TPA_Extensions": {
                                                "SeatsRemaining": {
                                                    "Number": 9,
                                                    "BelowMin": false
                                                },
                                                "Cabin": {
                                                    "Cabin": "Y"
                                                },
                                                "Meal": {
                                                    "Code": "F"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "FareBasisCodes": {
                                    "FareBasisCode": [{
                                            "BookingCode": "Z",
                                            "DepartureAirportCode": "LAX",
                                            "AvailabilityBreak": false,
                                            "ArrivalAirportCode": "MSP",
                                            "content": "ZT"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "BookingCode": "Z",
                                            "DepartureAirportCode": "MSP",
                                            "AvailabilityBreak": true,
                                            "ArrivalAirportCode": "JFK",
                                            "content": "ZT"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "BookingCode": "Z",
                                            "DepartureAirportCode": "JFK",
                                            "AvailabilityBreak": false,
                                            "ArrivalAirportCode": "MSP",
                                            "content": "ZT14"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "BookingCode": "Z",
                                            "DepartureAirportCode": "MSP",
                                            "AvailabilityBreak": true,
                                            "ArrivalAirportCode": "LAX",
                                            "content": "ZT14"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "PassengerTypeQuantity": {
                                    "Quantity": 2,
                                    "Code": "ADT",
                                    "Changeable": false
                                },
                                "PassengerFare": {
                                    "FareConstruction": {
                                        "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                                        "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                        "Amount": 229.77
                                    },
                                    "TotalFare": {
                                        "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                        "DecimalPlaces": 0,
                                        "Amount": 934.28
                                    },
                                    "Taxes": {
                                        "TotalFare": null,
                                        "Tax": [{
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "US1",
                                                "Amount": 55.02,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "ZP",
                                                "Amount": 13.09,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "ZP",
                                                "Amount": 13.09,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "ZP",
                                                "Amount": 13.09,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "ZP",
                                                "Amount": 13.09,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "AY",
                                                "Amount": 17.88,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "AY",
                                                "Amount": 17.88,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "XF",
                                                "Amount": 14.36,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "XF",
                                                "Amount": 14.36,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "XF",
                                                "Amount": 14.36,
                                                "content": ""
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                                "TaxCode": "XF",
                                                "Amount": 14.36,
                                                "content": ""
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "BaseFare": {
                                        "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                                        "DecimalPlaces": 0,
                                        "Amount": 229.77
                                    },
                                    "EquivFare": {
                                        "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                        "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                        "Amount": 733.7
                                    }
                                },
                                "Endorsements": {
                                    "NonRefundableIndicator": true
                                },
                                "TPA_Extensions": {
                                    "FareCalcLine": {
                                        "Info": "LAX SY X/MSP SY NYC128.37SY X/MSP SY LAX101.40USD229.77END ZPLAXMSPJFKMSP XFLAX4.5MSP4.5JFK4.5MSP4.5"
                                    }
                                },
                                "FareInfos": {
                                    "FareInfo": [{
                                            "FareReference": "Z",
                                            "TPA_Extensions": {
                                                "SeatsRemaining": {
                                                    "Number": 9,
                                                    "BelowMin": false
                                                },
                                                "Cabin": {
                                                    "Cabin": "Y"
                                                },
                                                "Meal": {
                                                    "Code": "F"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "FareReference": "Z",
                                            "TPA_Extensions": {
                                                "SeatsRemaining": {
                                                    "Number": 9,
                                                    "BelowMin": false
                                                },
                                                "Cabin": {
                                                    "Cabin": "Y"
                                                },
                                                "Meal": {
                                                    "Code": "F"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "FareReference": "Z",
                                            "TPA_Extensions": {
                                                "SeatsRemaining": {
                                                    "Number": 9,
                                                    "BelowMin": false
                                                },
                                                "Cabin": {
                                                    "Cabin": "Y"
                                                },
                                                "Meal": {
                                                    "Code": "F"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "FareReference": "Z",
                                            "TPA_Extensions": {
                                                "SeatsRemaining": {
                                                    "Number": 9,
                                                    "BelowMin": false
                                                },
                                                "Cabin": {
                                                    "Cabin": "Y"
                                                },
                                                "Meal": {
                                                    "Code": "F"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "FareBasisCodes": {
                                    "FareBasisCode": [{
                                            "BookingCode": "Z",
                                            "DepartureAirportCode": "LAX",
                                            "AvailabilityBreak": false,
                                            "ArrivalAirportCode": "MSP",
                                            "content": "ZTIN"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "BookingCode": "Z",
                                            "DepartureAirportCode": "MSP",
                                            "AvailabilityBreak": true,
                                            "ArrivalAirportCode": "JFK",
                                            "content": "ZTIN"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "BookingCode": "Z",
                                            "DepartureAirportCode": "JFK",
                                            "AvailabilityBreak": false,
                                            "ArrivalAirportCode": "MSP",
                                            "content": "ZT14IN"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "BookingCode": "Z",
                                            "DepartureAirportCode": "MSP",
                                            "AvailabilityBreak": true,
                                            "ArrivalAirportCode": "LAX",
                                            "content": "ZT14IN"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                "PassengerTypeQuantity": {
                                    "Quantity": 2,
                                    "Code": "INF",
                                    "Changeable": false
                                },
                                "PassengerFare": {
                                    "FareConstruction": {
                                        "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                                        "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                        "Amount": 0.0
                                    },
                                    "TotalFare": {
                                        "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                        "DecimalPlaces": 0,
                                        "Amount": 0.0
                                    },
                                    "Taxes": null,
                                    "BaseFare": {
                                        "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                                        "DecimalPlaces": 0,
                                        "Amount": 0.0
                                    },
                                    "EquivFare": {
                                        "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                        "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                        "Amount": 0.0
                                    }
                                },
                                "Endorsements": {
                                    "NonRefundableIndicator": true
                                },
                                "TPA_Extensions": {
                                    "FareCalcLine": {
                                        "Info": "LAX SY X/MSP SY NYC0.00SY X/MSP SY LAX0.00USD0.00END"
                                    }
                                },
                                "FareInfos": {
                                    "FareInfo": [{
                                            "FareReference": "Z",
                                            "TPA_Extensions": {
                                                "SeatsRemaining": {
                                                    "Number": 9,
                                                    "BelowMin": false
                                                },
                                                "Cabin": {
                                                    "Cabin": "Y"
                                                },
                                                "Meal": {
                                                    "Code": "F"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "FareReference": "Z",
                                            "TPA_Extensions": {
                                                "SeatsRemaining": {
                                                    "Number": 9,
                                                    "BelowMin": false
                                                },
                                                "Cabin": {
                                                    "Cabin": "Y"
                                                },
                                                "Meal": {
                                                    "Code": "F"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "FareReference": "Z",
                                            "TPA_Extensions": {
                                                "SeatsRemaining": {
                                                    "Number": 9,
                                                    "BelowMin": false
                                                },
                                                "Cabin": {
                                                    "Cabin": "Y"
                                                },
                                                "Meal": {
                                                    "Code": "F"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "FareReference": "Z",
                                            "TPA_Extensions": {
                                                "SeatsRemaining": {
                                                    "Number": 9,
                                                    "BelowMin": false
                                                },
                                                "Cabin": {
                                                    "Cabin": "Y"
                                                },
                                                "Meal": {
                                                    "Code": "F"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "FareInfos": {
                        "FareInfo": [{
                                "FareReference": "Z",
                                "TPA_Extensions": {
                                    "SeatsRemaining": {
                                        "Number": 9,
                                        "BelowMin": false
                                    },
                                    "Cabin": {
                                        "Cabin": "Y"
                                    },
                                    "Meal": {
                                        "Code": "F"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "FareReference": "Z",
                                "TPA_Extensions": {
                                    "SeatsRemaining": {
                                        "Number": 9,
                                        "BelowMin": false
                                    },
                                    "Cabin": {
                                        "Cabin": "Y"
                                    },
                                    "Meal": {
                                        "Code": "F"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "FareReference": "Z",
                                "TPA_Extensions": {
                                    "SeatsRemaining": {
                                        "Number": 9,
                                        "BelowMin": false
                                    },
                                    "Cabin": {
                                        "Cabin": "Y"
                                    },
                                    "Meal": {
                                        "Code": "F"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "FareReference": "Z",
                                "TPA_Extensions": {
                                    "SeatsRemaining": {
                                        "Number": 9,
                                        "BelowMin": false
                                    },
                                    "Cabin": {
                                        "Cabin": "Y"
                                    },
                                    "Meal": {
                                        "Code": "F"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "TPA_Extensions": {
                        "DivideInParty": {
                            "Indicator": false
                        }
                    },
                    "ItinTotalFare": {
                        "FareConstruction": {
                            "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                            "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                            "Amount": 919.08
                        },
                        "TotalFare": {
                            "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                            "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                            "Amount": 3737.12
                        },
                        "Taxes": {
                            "TotalFare": null,
                            "Tax": [{
                                "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                                "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                                "TaxCode": "TOTALTAX",
                                "Amount": 802.32,
                                "content": ""
                            }]
                        },
                        "BaseFare": {
                            "CurrencyCode": "USD",
                            "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                            "Amount": 919.08
                        },
                        "EquivFare": {
                            "CurrencyCode": "BRL",
                            "DecimalPlaces": 2,
                            "Amount": 2934.8
                        }
                    }
                }],
                "TicketingInfo": {
                    "TicketType": "eTicket",
                    "ValidInterline": "Yes"
                },
                "TPA_Extensions": {
                    "TagID": "BargainFinderMaxRQ~8733b3ea-c954-4782-8e75-0332238e6721~1",
                    "ValidatingCarrier": [{
                        "Default": null
                    }]
                },
                "SequenceNumber": 1
            }]
        }
    },
    "Links": [{
            "rel": "self",
            "": ""
        },
        {
            "rel": "linkTemplate",
            "": ""
        },
        {
            "rel": "tagLookupLinkTemplate",
            "": ""
        },
        {
            "rel": "paginatedRequestLinkTemplate",
            "": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

My request have 2 ADT, 2 CNN11 and 2 INF. Why SABRE is returning 4 ADT and 2 INF?

Comment: Downvoters, if you don't know about Sabre, don't downvote. *You* don't understand the question. Especially if you don't understand the difference between 2 ADT and 2 CNN11, don't behave like 2 INF

Comment: It may be that the *airline* doesn't have such tickets and can only return ADT for the CNN11. I'm using the acronyms intentionally to ... infuriate the downvoters

Comment: Do you get that for *every* result, or only for specific airlines? What happens if you use different days? This may be a valid result

Comment: It´s doesn´t  occur in all requests. Sometimes, SABRE returns the the rigth combination. I think like you, this can occur when there is no discount for children. But, I do no if it´s right.

Comment: Only your Sabre contact can give you a definite answer - results are also affected by your company's contract or how Sabre has configured its results for your company. It's *better* to show a result with adult fares than no result at all. Many OTAs also require a mix of economy, business, first results to give customers more options if there are no Economy results

Comment: Ok, thank you, Panagiotis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the response here:

[Passenger type mismatch in search request and response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761024/passenger-type-mismatch-in-search-request-and-response?rq=1)

When the Value for XOFares in the request is true, SABRE returns: NO COMBINABLE FARES FOR CLASS USED.

By default this value is false, then SABRE replaces children with adults.

Answer (score 1):

If C11 (CNN11 doesn't exist) pax type is not applicable, the system can default to ADT.

```
*IA«                                                            
 1 SY 424Z 02OCT 1 LAXMSP SS4  1300  1833  /DCSY /E             
 2 SY 249Z 02OCT 1 MSPJFK SS4  1945  2335  /DCSY /E             
 3 SY 240Z 27OCT 5 JFKMSP SS4  0700  0905  /DCSY /E             
 4 SY 423Z 27OCT 5 MSPLAX SS4  1005  1200  /DCSY /E             

WPPCNN11«                                                       
‡FORMAT‡                                                        

WPPC11«                                                         
02OCT DEPARTURE DATE-----LAST DAY TO PURCHASE 30SEP/1341        
       BASE FARE      EQUIV AMT  TAXES/FEES/CHARGES    TOTAL    
 4-    USD229.77      BRL732.29     200.20XT       BRL932.49ADT 
    XT     54.92US      52.24ZP      35.68AY      57.36XF       
          919.08        2929.16     800.80           3729.96TTL 
ADT-04  ZT ZT14                                                 
 LAX SY X/MSP SY NYC128.37SY X/MSP SY LAX101.40USD229.77END ZP  
 LAXMSPJFKMSP XFLAX4.5MSP4.5JFK4.5MSP4.5                        
NONREF/SVCCHGPLUSFAREDIF/CXL BY FLT TIME OR NOVALUE
```

> C11 NOT APPLICABLE - ADT FARE USED - VERIFY RESTRICTIONS

```
VALIDATING CARRIER - SY                                         
BAG ALLOWANCE     -LAXJFK-NIL/SY                                
1STCHECKED BAG FEE-LAXJFK-BRL79.67/SY/UP TO 50 POUNDS/23 KILOGR 
AMS AND UP TO 62 LINEAR INCHES/158 LINEAR CENTIMETERS           
2NDCHECKED BAG FEE-LAXJFK-BRL111.54/SY/UP TO 50 POUNDS/23 KILOG 
RAMS AND UP TO 62 LINEAR INCHES/158 LINEAR CENTIMETERS          
BAG ALLOWANCE     -JFKLAX-NIL/SY                                
1STCHECKED BAG FEE-JFKLAX-BRL79.67/SY/UP TO 50 POUNDS/23 KILOGR 
AMS AND UP TO 62 LINEAR INCHES/158 LINEAR CENTIMETERS          ‡
```

If this is not desired, you can force the C11 pax type but if it's not applicable, no fare will be returned.

```
WPPC11‡XO«                                                      
NO RULES VALID FOR PASSENGER TYPE/CLASS OF SERVICE‡33
```